# bevel modifier after boolean modifier

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I want to use bevel after boolean. I have 2 boolean modifier for my object. If I put bevel after the boolean, the bevel doesnt work.
[image]

[image]

When I put bevel first, it works but there is some stain in my object.
[image]

How to solve this problem? Should I manually bevel each edge or there is a another way?

Comment: I think this is a smoothing or normals problem. First try going to edit mode, select the whole mesh and then press Shift+N to recalculate normals. If that doesn't work, go to the object data properties tab (which is over the materials tab on the right) and then go to normals and enable auto smooth. Try playing with the angle.

Comment: @ChaudhryYousuf thank you for commenting. I already use auto smooth with angle 30. I try to change the angle. The bigger the angel the boolean shape gets wird

Comment: Did you try recalculating normals?

Comment: @ChaudhryYousuf I did and the stain is still there

Comment: Can you share your .blend file? Maybe changing some settings will remove the stain.

Comment: @ChaudhryYousuf i'm sorry I really want to share the file but the loading in blender exchange is too slow and the progress is not running

Comment: Try adding it in wetransfer, it works.

Answer (score 1):

The bevel may be being held back by the “clamp overlap” setting. Turn that off and see what happens.

The stain is normal flaws, and is happening because the shade smooth is averaging the normals between the bevel faces and the large ones that are meant to look flat, affecting the large flat ones as well. The solutions for this problem vary. Most use “Inset Faces” after all modifiers have been applied.

Comment: can you explain in more detail which part should I use inset faces?

Comment: All the parts that are supposed to look flat: the side of the thing, for example. Inserting a face with just a tiny bit of margin around it will make the smooth shading not try to make it look curved